# how to use Provider to displaying Snackbar When Product Quantity Reaches a certain value in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, provider, snackbar

I'm working on a Flutter application where I'm trying to implement a quantity selector for products. The desired behavior is as follows: When the "Add" button is clicked, the quantity should increment by 1, and a snackbar should display a message. Subsequent clicks on the "Add" button should increment the quantity by 2, 3, and so on, up to a maximum of 10. When the quantity reaches 10, I want a snackbar to display a message, and any further clicks on the "Add" button should not have any effect, but when the quantity reaches 10 and i click on the "Add" button the snackbar message keep on showing. What i want it when it reaches 10 a snackbar message pop up.

The Provider Class

```
class QuantitySelector extends ChangeNotifier {
  final Map<int, int> _quantities = {}; 

  int getQuantityValue(int productId) =>
      _quantities[productId] ??
      1;

  snackBar(context, int productId) {
    final currentValue = _quantities[productId] ?? 1;
    if (currentValue <= 10) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          elevation: 0.0,
          shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero),
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF6DBD28),
          content: Row(
            children: [
              const Icon(
                Icons.done,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              buildSizeBoxWidth(10),
              Text(
                AppStrings.kSnackBarText,
                style: AppStyles.kSnackBarTextStyles,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
          dismissDirection: DismissDirection.none,
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(
            bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 160,
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  void quantityIncrement(int productId) {
    final currentValue = _quantities[productId] ?? 1;
    if (currentValue < 10) {
      _quantities[productId] = currentValue + 1;
      notifyListeners();
    }
  } 

  void quantityDecrement(int productId) {
    final currentValue = _quantities[productId] ?? 1;
    if (currentValue > 1) {
      _quantities[productId] = currentValue - 1;
      notifyListeners();
    }
  } 

  void resetProductQuantity(int productId) {
    _quantities.remove(productId);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Color quantityIncrementButtonColor(int productId) {
    final currentValue = _quantities[productId] ?? 1;
    if (currentValue < 10) {
      return AppColors.kPrimaryColor;
    }
    return AppColors.kGrayColor.withOpacity(0.5);
  }

  Color quantityDecrementButtonColor(int productId) {
    final currentValue = _quantities[productId] ?? 1;
    if (currentValue > 1) {
      return AppColors.kPrimaryColor;
    }
    return AppColors.kGrayColor.withOpacity(0.5);
  }
}
```

```
class ProductQuantitySelectorRow extends StatelessWidget {
  final int productId;
  const ProductQuantitySelectorRow({super.key, required this.productId});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final quantitySelector = Provider.of<QuantitySelector>(context);
    return Row(
      children: [
        ProductQuantitySelector(
          color: quantitySelector.quantityDecrementButtonColor(productId),
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
          symbol: '-',
          onTap: () {
            quantitySelector.quantityDecrement(productId);
            // showCustom(context);
          },
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 30,
          width: 20,
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              quantitySelector.getQuantityValue(productId).toString(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        ProductQuantitySelector(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
          symbol: '+',
          color: quantitySelector.quantityIncrementButtonColor(productId),
          onTap: () {
            quantitySelector.quantityIncrement(productId);
           quantitySelector.snackBar(context,productId);
          },
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: the `snackabar` have a time to popup.  so i think you need to add some bounce time to popup the next `snackabar`

Answer (score 0):

In the QuantitySelector class, I've made updates to improve the snackbar functionality, while maintaining code simplicity and reusability. Instead of having a separate snackBar method, I've integrated the snackbar display directly into the quantityIncrement method. This simplifies the code and eliminates the need for an additional method.

```
class QuantitySelector extends ChangeNotifier {
  final Map<int, int> _quantities = {};

  int getQuantityValue(int productId) => _quantities[productId] ?? 1; 

  void quantityIncrement(int productId, BuildContext context) {
    final currentValue = _quantities[productId] ?? 1;
    if (currentValue < 10) {
      _quantities[productId] = currentValue + 1;
     showSnackBar(context);
    } 
    notifyListeners();
  } 

  void quantityDecrement(BuildContext context, int productId) {
    final currentValue = _quantities[productId] ?? 1;
    if (currentValue > 1) {
      _quantities[productId] = currentValue - 1;
      showSnackBar(context);
      notifyListeners();
    }
  } 
  void resetProductQuantity(int productId) {
    _quantities.remove(productId);
    notifyListeners(); 
  }
}
```